# Will SQLAlchemy update the content of objects in the middle of a session?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

In the SQLAlchemy docs it says this:

"When using a Session, it’s important to note that the objects which are associated with it are proxy objects to the transaction being held by the Session - there are a variety of events that will cause objects to re-access the database in order to keep synchronized. It is possible to “detach” objects from a Session, and to continue using them, though this practice has its caveats. It’s intended that usually, you’d re-associate detached objects with another Session when you want to work with them again, so that they can resume their normal task of representing database state."
[[http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html]](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html%5d)

If I am in the middle of a session in which I read some objects, do some manipulations and more queries and save some objects, before committing, is there a risk that changes to the dbase by other users will unexpectedly update my objects while I am working with them?

In other words, what are the "variety of events" referred to above?

Is the answer to set the transaction isolation level to maximum? (I am using postureSQL with Flask-SQLAlchemy and Flask-Restful, if any of that matters.)

Answer (score 1):

No, SQLAlchemy does not monitor the database for changes or update your objects whenever it feels like it. I can imagine it would be quite expensive operation. The "variety of events" refers more to SQLAlchemy's internal state. I'm not familiar with all the "events" but for example when objects are marked as expired, SQLAlchemy automatically reloads them from the database. One such case is calling `session.commit()` and accessing any object's property again.

More here: [Documentation about expiring objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#refreshing-expiring)